# Какой элемент находится в верхней видимой части страницы

Tags: jquery

Как определить ( или скопировать, или обернуть в тег), что находится в красной зоне?

[image]

Comment: @Idaho37,  Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @eicto, самому интересно, а реально ли, в принципе, получить самый верхний элемент на **мониторе**. ИМХО -- нет.

Comment: если это <p> то по-моему есть  шанс, а  если это всё <pre> то надо думать.

Comment: это всё <p>. Вот, пока это набросал http://jsfiddle.net/Idaho37/KvEQt/. Но если крутить колёсиком, то абзацы пропускаются, надо сравнивать в промежутках. Этот способ какой то сложный, 30 абзацев - может ещё ничего, но когда их 1000, то думаю будут проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: можно наверное высоту строки для начала определить, потом с помощью выделения вычислить примерно, и скорректировать. про определение координат выделенной области можно тут почитать: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328/815386

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже пригодиться. Но сейчас мне надо определение, которое не зависит от пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bJqqY/

15, 20 это надо margin поставить для p.